# How to set minimum number of charcter to search in angular js filter?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-filters

I am doing angular js filter .

Here I am searching customer name .

Everything is working fine ,but I want to modify it a bit .

Here after typing 2 character ,my search is working .

But my requirement is to start search immediately after typing the first character .
I have tried some code but its not working .

```html
 <tr class="gradeU" ng-repeat="x in invoice| filter:invoice_name | filter:customer_name:strLimit: 1">
```

Here I am using strLimit to do it.

But its not working at all.

I have attached a snap ,please have a look.

[image]

Any idea ?

Thank you

Comment: Why do you have 2 filters ? `| filter:invoice_name | filter:customer_name` Do you have 2 differents inputs ? 
Just remove `strLimit: 1`. Filter will automatically be fired when you start typing

Comment: remove `strLimit: 1` and try

Comment: Yes i have two filter field.

Comment: @sradha Ok then just remove `strLimit : 1`

Comment: @Weedoze But its not working .
After typing 2 character ,search is coming .

Comment: @Mr.7 ,after removing its not working at all.

Comment: @sradha Can you provide us with a plunkr/fiddle?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Works fine for me here ! Can you see anything missing from snippet and your original code #?

You don't even need the `strLimit:1` to achieve this.

```js
var app = angular.module('app',[]);
app.controller('Ctrl',function($scope){
  
  $scope.invoice = [{"id":123,"name":"Shrada"},
                    {"id":111,"name":"Vikram"},
                    {"id":342,"name":"Shrada"},
                    {"id":231,"name":"Melina"}
  
  ];
  
  });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>

<div ng-app="app" ng-controller="Ctrl">
  
  <input type="text" ng-model="invoice_name"/>
  <input type="text" ng-model="customer_name"/>
<div class="gradeU" ng-repeat="x in invoice| filter:invoice_name | filter:customer_name">    
  {{x.id}} - {{x.name}}
  </div>
  </div>
```

Comment: Can you please help me for this one  
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40798261/date-search-filter-is-not-working-in-angular-js

??