# Date search filter is not working in angular js

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-filters

I am new to angular js.
I am trying to implement date custom filter using date picker .
I have tried it , but I am not getting any idea to work out.
Below is my code.

```html
  <div class="col-sm-2 m-b-xs">
    <input type="text" name="from_date" class="form-control" placeholder="From" date-time view="date" auto-close="true" min-view="date" ng-model="from_date"  format="MMM-DD-YYYY" readonly />
      </div>
```

```html
   <tr class="gradeU" ng-repeat="x in invoice | filter:{created : from_date}">       
  <td style="text-align: center;">{{ x.created | datetime }}</td>      
</tr>
```

```js
JS SECTION 
function InvoiceControllers($scope, $stateParams, $http, $state) {
    $scope.filterData = {};
    $scope.invoice_listing = function (data) {
        var json = (function () {
            var json = null;
            $.ajax({
                'async': false,
                'global': false,
                'url': 'invoices/listing_invoice',
                'data': data,
                'dataType': "json",
                'success': function (data) {
                    // alert(data);
                    json = data;
                }
            });
            return json;
        })();
        //$scope.formData = {value : json};
        $scope.invoice = json;
    };
    var data = {};
    $scope.invoice_listing(data);

    $scope.filter_invoice = function () {
        var data = $scope.filterData;
        $scope.invoice_listing(data);
    };


}

function dateTime($filter) {
    return function (input) {
        if (input == null) {
            return "";
        }

        var _date = $filter('date')(new Date(input), 'MMM-dd-yyyy');
        return _date.toUpperCase();

    };
}

angular
        .module('inspinia')

        .controller('InvoiceControllers', InvoiceControllers)

        .filter('datetime', dateTime);
```

Here I have tried  the search part in from date section.
[image]

Any suggestion .Thank you

Comment: Please use "return _date;" instead of "return _date.toUpperCase();" in dateTime function.

Answer (score 0):

You get this issue because in your input field `from_date` set modal value as a date string. You need to format your date in same format you used in table column

```
var from_date = $filter('date')($scope.from_date, 'MMM-dd-yyyy');
$scope.invoice.filter({ created: from_date });
```